# Find subspaces $W, X, Y \subset \Bbb{R} ^2$ with $\Bbb R ^2 = X \oplus Y$ but $X ∩ W = Y ∩ W = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find subspaces $W, X, Y \subset \Bbb{R} ^2$ with $\Bbb R ^2 = X \oplus Y$ but $X ∩ W = Y ∩ W = \{0\}$.

I don't know how to relate the direct sum to the intersection, does the cancellation theorem apply here? If it does how, it's an intersection not an addition. Please help.

Comment: Let $W$ be the zero subspace, and $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What's the cancellation theorem?

Comment: @EnjoysMath, cancellation theory is if a + b = c + b, then a = c.

Comment: Isn't the cancellation on the vectors in the spaces.  Where would it apply here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X, Y$ be any two non-parallel lines intersecting at the origin.  Then any two vectors, one on one line, one on the other span $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Since all the intersections are zero if we let $W = \{0\}$, we have $X\bigoplus Y = \mathbb{R}^2$.  That's infinitely many examples I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X = \{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $Y = \{(y,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

$X + Y = \mathbb{R^2} = (x + y, y)$

equating the sum of the two subspaces to the $0$ vector:

$(x + y, y) = (0,0)$,

which demonstrates that $y = 0$, $x = 0$ are the only two values in which we can obtain the $0$ vector. Therefore, $$X \oplus Y = \mathbb{R^2}.$$

Now, we must find a $W$ that satisfies $X\cap W = Y \cap W = \{0\}.$

This subspace must be disjoint (excluding the $0$ vector) with $X:x$-axis, and $Y: \text{line } y = x$. In $\mathbb{R^2}$, our options are a bit restrictive compared to higher dimensions. One option is the subspace $W = \{(-w,w) \in \mathbb{R^2}:w \in \mathbb{R}\}$, which mathematically represents the line $y = -x$. The three lines in $\mathbb{R^2}$ all intersect at $0$, but have no other elements in common.